# how to pass value from fancybox popup model to parent window asp.net

Tags: fancybox, parent

I have 3 buttons in my fancybox, I want to check which button is clicked in fancy box and then I have to update parent content accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could define some hidden input type in your parent and do something like:

```
//onclick of some button on fancybox
window.parent.document.getElementById("yourHiddenFieldId").value = "someValue";
```

Did you mean something like this.
Hope it helps